# Mutual updates don't work in RxJava while were working in conventional listeners

Tags: java, asynchronous, rx-java, rx-java2, event-dispatch-thread

I need to make two values be in sync, but to allow any of them to be changed. In plain EDT listeners I was able just to guard changes with `boolean` flag. Each change is done only if flug is down and while changing, flag is up. This was doing a job. But now I switched to reactive and everything was broken.

Below I am listenting `yProperty` and change `offset` according to and and also listening for `offset` and changing `y` property according to it.

```
    doubleValues(yProperty())
        .observeOn(SwingScheduler.INSTANCE)
        .subscribe(newValue -> {
        if(!changing) {
            changing = true;
            originNode.setOffset(originNode.getXOffset(), newValue);
            changing = false;
        }
    });

    offsetChanges(getOriginNode())
        .observeOn(SwingScheduler.INSTANCE)
        .subscribe(point -> {
        if(!changing) {
            changing = true;
            setY(point.getY());
            changing = false;
        }
    });
```

Since I have `observeOn` in a chain, each action is wrapped into `Runnable` and posted at the end of `EDT` queue and executed when `changing` flag is already off. This leads to infinite loop of mutual calls.

Are there any means in Rx to solve such cases?

---

`changing` is class variable, it is not final. Under the hood any call of first consumer triggers second one and it triggers first one and so on.

Comment: what is `changing`?  afaik you can't edit a variable outside the scope of the lambda, since they must be final

Comment: it is class variable

Comment: Some APIs tend to have a "fireNotification" property on the mutator method so this type of cycling back and forth can be prevented. If you control setOffset and setY, you could conditionally not fire off the change notification. Alternatively, you can not call setOffset and setY if there was no actual change in the value, just that first round of notification back and forth.